# Postgresql results

Tags: postgresql

I have question about PostgreSQL. I would like to return different results for `select all` based on the client IP and I want it on the database level.  In other words, I want to change query string. Should I change the PostgreSQL code and compile it based on my idea?

Answer (score 1):

In PostgreSQL 9.5 and newer you could use row-level security to do this. I don't think it's a great idea, but that's the way to approach it if you're going to attempt it.

Comment: Rules also come to mind to "change the query string".

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yeah, not sure how you'd apply that based on source IP though. Maybe with a `WHERE` condition on the rule.